# Проектирование простой базы данных товаров

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

есть PostgreSql база, в ней категории, например, овощи, фрукты, крупы.

в каждой категории есть продукты, например, помидоры, картошка, буряк.

у каждого продукта есть свойства, например, витамины B7 А3.

Сейчас сделал одну таблицу - "товаты", где есть поле "имя", содержащее овощи, фрукты, крупы.

И, на каждый элемент в "товары" по таблице, где primary ключ - PK_fruits, например, в таблице фруктов и 2 поля - имя, витамин.

Теперь на каждое имя, например, фрукта, думаю создавать таблицу аналогично.

Правильный ли это подход, или можно улучшить?

Comment: Напишите DDL скрипты ваших таблиц, по вопросу в таком виде сложно понять, что именно вы делаете. Если подозрение, что делаете что-то не то.